# Call async method in blazor in html attribute

Tags: razor, lambda, async-await, delegates, blazor

I'm trying to call an async function to retrieve data from an input and pass it to either the `src` or `style` attribute of an element depending on what it is. However, when I try to await it I get an error of:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

```html
  <div class="swiper-slide" style="
        background-image: url(@await LinkConverter.GetLinkFromData(media)">
  </div>
```

But when I try to use a lambda expression like:

```html
  <div class="swiper-slide">
         <video src="@async () => await LinkConverter.GetLinkFromData(media, true)" width="320" height="240">
         </video>
  </div>
```

I get the following error(which I don't understand):

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

The function is inside of a foreach and some if statements so I would much rather not have to do something where I create a list of the results at `OnIntializedAsync` and end up duplicating my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a component for this.

Your foreach might be something like this

```razor
@foreach(var media in MediaItems)
{
  <DisplayMedia @key=media FetchMediaTask=@(()=>LinkConverter.GetLinkFromData(media)) />
}
```

And DisplayMedia would be

```csharp
@typeparam T
<div class="swiper-slide" style="
      background-image: url(@Data)">
</div>
@code
{
 [Parameter] public Func<Task<T>> FetchMediaTask { get; set; }
 T Data;
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool first)
 {
  if (first)
  {
   Data = (T)await FetchMediaTask();
   StateHasChanged();
  }
 }
}
```

In this way, you can render the `divs` and await the `GetLinkFromData` inside the Component, which is supported.

Demo: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GEbcFnEm587VpE6g22

Comment: Nice. It gave me an idea for another task :)